# Serve React on IIS with MVC C# Web.Api backend

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, iis-7, react-router

I have created a React project (using create-react-app), which communicates to a MVC C# web api 2 Backend. Everything works fine in development, using the React Proxy.

I now want to move to a production site. The production site is using IIS 7. All my MVC C# controllers have the url /api/*.

What I believe I need to do, is for IIS to redirect all calls to the react index.html file if /API/ is not in the route. This way the react router can handle the routing. Any calls to the server will have the prefix /api/ and this is where MVC should route the call to the controller.

I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use IIS to rewrite all urls that weren't in /api/* /content/* /static/* to the react index.html file.

Solution here:
[IIS rewrite condition for React MVC App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594026/iis-rewrite-condition-for-react-mvc-app)