# IIS rewrite condition for React MVC App

Tags: reactjs, iis, url-rewriting

I have created a create-react-app and am trying to publish to a production site.

My goal is to have all calls to /api/* go through to the MVC Server application's controller. 
Also serve any static files from /content/* and /static/*

All other calls should serve the 1 file /index.html (which is where my react files live and they will handle the routing.

I am using the IIS Rewrite module, and I am trying  to use the requested URL "Does Not MAtch the pattern" with regexp.

MY current IIS setup ignores the "do not rewrite if pattern matches" and rewrites everything to index.html

Here is the IIS setup:
[image]

and here is the web.config. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
 <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Rewrite" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                    <match url="(.*)/api/(.*)|(.*)/content/(.*)|(.*)/static/(.*)" negate="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                    <conditions>
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by using the Conditions. My solution is:

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Rewrite" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                    <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(/api/)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(/content/)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(/static/)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```